# How to send request to telegram for use telegram api

Tags: php, json, api, telegram, telegram-webhook

I have a app using the telegram API.

And I have an `api_id` and an `api_hash`.

Now I want to register a user to his telegram account (using the API).

I read [this page](https://core.telegram.org/api/auth).
It said  for example for [`auth.sendCode`](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode) to use this code:

```
auth.sentCode#efed51d9 phone_registered:Bool phone_code_hash:string send_call_timeout:int is_password:Bool = auth.SentCode;
auth.sentAppCode#e325edcf phone_registered:Bool phone_code_hash:string send_call_timeout:int is_password:Bool = auth.SentCode;
---functions---
auth.sendCode#768d5f4d phone_number:string sms_type:int api_id:int api_hash:string lang_code:string = auth.SentCode;
```

Should I send the URL or what?
For example in the telegram bot API for `get me` function we should send requests to this url:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot#key/getme
```

Is the problem this example?

If there is a result on **github** or **here** please tell me .

Answer (score 1):

The difference between bot api and user api is the type of communication, **bot api** use **Https protocol**, **user api** use **Transmission Control Protocol** (tcp).
You should use a client not a browser, I suggest you to use [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto). 
I'm sorry for my english